# How to populate Array of Strings from text file

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm trying to get the information from Stock.txt and to transfer it into an array of strings, each index being a new line in the file. I get a warning:

Duplicate local variable. What is the problem, is it out of scope?

```
public static List<String> getStock(List<String> stockText){
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        File input = new File("Stock.txt");
        scanner = new Scanner(input);
        String[] info = null;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            info = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        }
        List<String> stockText = Arrays.asList(info);
    }   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
    return stockText;
}
```

}

Comment: `stockText` is the name of your input parameter and the local variable you create inside the `try` block

Comment: You're passing `stockText` as a parameter to the method and then create another local variable with the same name. You never use the paremeter so you can remove it from the declaration.

Comment: Did you try creating object of scanner class i.e. Scanner input = new Scanner(input);

Comment: Thank you all for the input, I understand the problem now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is, `stockText` is an argument and later you create a variable with the same name. That's not allowed. If your intention was to use the same variable, remove `List<String>` from `List<String> stockText = Arrays.asList(info);`

Otherwise, give the variable another name.

Comment: Even better would be to remove the method parameter  as it is never used. Just create a List inside of the function and then return it.

Comment: @Amongalen I usually don't make suggestions of this type because many codes posted in SO are minimized, and there might be some residues of the original code that don't make sense in the minimized version, but is important in the full version.